# Why does a file upload php script not work on a new server?

Tags: php, forms, upload, server

I moved a php srcipt I had running on a free server to my own server (apache 2 on raspberry pi) and it didn't work any more. You'll find the script below - it returns "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.".

I have no idea what could be causing this. Here are most of the thigs that I tried/observed:

- the folder on my raspberry pi server is password protected. i removed the password, but it bore no results
- my server is behind a router and the forwarding works. i can access anything i upload  from within and without the local network.
- php.ini allows uploading files

file_upload.php:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 2000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "JPG, JPEG, PNG or GIF.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Error.";
  }
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: check the php ini upload parameters.They might have lesser limits than the previous

Comment: I think the file doesn't even exist, do you have permission to reach it?

Comment: If the file is uploaded, but cannot be moved, `move_uploaded_file` issues a warning in addition to returning false. Make sure you capture that warning to see what it is. Most likely, you don't have permissions on the target directory, or that directory doesn't exist.

Comment: folder your writing into isn't write enabled for the user which runs the httpd. check your storage folder permissions

Comment: so i should try chmod 757, right?

Comment: solved. had to change folder permissions to 777/757.